# Storybook: how to create two versions

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon, storybook-addon-doc

Is it possible to hide some content in the storybook and create two versions of it?

For example: `1.0` and `review`, so, in the `prod` version I'd like to hide this folder `review` and in the `dev` version, I'd like to show it.

#### Dev version

[image]

#### Prod version

[image]

#### What should be the best way to achieve this?